# Cannot access Angular Component directly from the browser

Tags: angularjs

I have a small web app that uses Angular 1.5 Components. When I fire up the sever, the browser redirects me to http://127.0.0.1:50001/welcome, which is expected, and the welcome page shows up. If I, say, want to create a new user, I click the link, the URL changes to http://127.0.0.1:50001/welcome/newUser and the new user form turns up.

The issue happens when I try to access URLs directly (or refresh the page) - the page simply doesn't load. No error appears in the console - nothing happens.

My configuration is as follow:

Root Component:

```
.component('webGuiComponent', {
  template: '<ng-outlet></ng-outlet>',
  $routeConfig: [
    { path: '/welcome/...', name: 'Welcome', component: 'welcomeComponent', useAsDefault: true }
  ]
})

.value('$routerRootComponent', 'webGuiComponent');
```

Welcome Components:

```
.component('welcomeComponent', {
  template: '<header></header><ng-outlet></ng-outlet>',
  $routeConfig: [
    { path: '/', name: 'Index', component: 'indexComponent', useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/newUser', name: 'NewUser', component: 'newUser' }
  ]
})

.component('indexComponent', {
  templateUrl: '/app/components/welcome/index.html'
});
```

New User Component:

```
.component('newUser', {
  controller: 'userController',
  templateUrl: '/app/components/user/new.html'
})
```

Navigation link uses standard ng-links:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" ng-link="['/Welcome/Index']">Web GUI</a>
<a class="navbar-brand" ng-link="['/Welcome/NewUser']">Sign Up</a>
```

Does anyone know why navigation works when done via ng-link but not when accessing URLs directly?

Comment: when you load [http://127.0.0.1:50001/welcome/newUser](http://127.0.0.1:50001/welcome/newUser) directly in the browser does it loads anything, what server technology you are using node/asp.net etc?

Comment: It doesn't load anything at all - the page remains 'white' as if the website had nothing at that address. I'm using Node's http-server for dev but the same happens when deployed on Tomcat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add server side route for all the paths you may have route defined in client side which will render your main page. Implementation depends on what server side technology you are using.

Or you have to use #based Url's

**Explanation**

When you don't have # based URL browser goes to server to fetch the resource but does not finds anything. So when you define server side routings it serves the main page and then client side routing takes place.

Comment: This makes sense and it also makes me feel silly for not realizing it before :) I'll either find out how to use #URLs with Angular components or how to map them at the server-side. Thanks.

Comment: The reason why your code works when you click is because you're preventing navigation to a URL which would not normally be found by the server. Like Madhu Ranjan says,  if you try to access one of those URLs directly, there is no JavaScript to intercept. I think the easiest way to implement hashes is to insert them immediately after the correct page URL like so `http://127.0.0.1:50001/welcome/#newUser` or if you require more information, you can do it in a sneaky "fake directory" way like so: `http://127.0.0.1:50001/welcome/#/newUser/newUserParameter/AnotherParameter`

Comment: @Madhu Ranjan. I have the same issue. I have already done server side  routing in web.config i.e. url rewrite. I am using IIS as a web server

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup Url Rewriting in the server to rewrite all urls to the index page or default route at the back-end.