# Change URL path for HashLocationStrategy

Tags: angular

Originally I had an error 404 when refreshing the page. I fixed that problem by implementing the hashlocationstrategy, but now when I refresh the page instead of error 404, it goes to the root index.html, which is not the correct location I want. Instead I would like it to refresh on the page it is currently on. So for example www.site.com/#/form and it stays on that page when refreshed. Can this be done with hashlocationstrategy in angular2?

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {router} from './app.router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';


import { UsercommentsComponent } from './usercomments/usercomments.component';
import { FormComponent } from './form/form.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    UsercommentsComponent,
    FormComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    router,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [ { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: It can be done, but it depends on your server side technology, look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172462/cannot-access-angular-component-directly-from-the-browser/37254775#37254775

Comment: If I'm only using Angular2 and no backend server language currently. Is there another way I can achieve this? I was looking at PathLocationStrategy, but I don't fully understand it. Is this something I can use or maybe a different method of getting the page to refresh properly?

Comment: But to serve the page you should be using ng serve  (Angular CLI node server) or something similar, if using Node (ng serve from Angular CLI) it should be taken care automatically, or if you have written your custom code you have to add that to your Server.js\ts page

Comment: The issue doesn't happen if I use ng serve to run the app locally, but when I upload it to my ftp server, that's when the 404 issue happens, which brought me to HashLocationStrategy. I guess it's different when you are hosted on a website versus being on localhost:4200